# How to clone a project with Xcode to a local volume

Tags: xcode4

I am attempting to clone an XCode project using the Organizer. I am following the example apple gives to a tee (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-repositories_organizer/articles/cloning_repository.html).   My location path is /Volumes/Share/Projects/XCode   Using Finder I verified that Share/Projects/XCode exists and that I have read + write access to it. However, whatever I attempt, XCode invariably returns a "host is unreachable" error.

Btw, all my attempts to whatever folder (local or shared) are failing. I must be missing something really basic but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried cloning it manually? You don't have to use Xcode.

Comment: @Abizem; yep manually works just fine. I know I don't have to use Xcode, I just don't get why it doesn't work according to the most basic example.